# Using waypoints for scroll on animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-waypoints, waypoint

Been struggling to replicate a css animation on scroll using waypoints.js

This is the animation: https://codepen.io/equinusocio/pen/KNYOxJ

```
<h1 class="reveal-text">
    I'm here.
</h1>


:root {
    --animation-delay: 0;
    --duration: 800ms;
    --iterations: 1;
}
/* ••·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•·•· */


.reveal-text,
.reveal-text::after {
    animation-delay: var(--animation-delay, 2s);
    animation-iteration-count: var(--iterations, 1);
    animation-duration: var(--duration, 800ms);
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.reveal-text {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10vw;
    animation-name: clip-text;
    color: #FFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: default;

    &::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #f2f98b;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: 0 50%;
        pointer-events: none;
        animation-name: text-revealer;
    }

}


@keyframes clip-text {
    from {
        clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0);
    }
    to {
        clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
    }
}


@keyframes text-revealer {

    0%, 50% {
        transform-origin: 0 50%;
    }

    60%, 100% {
        transform-origin: 100% 50%;     
    }


    60% {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scaleX(0);
    }
}
```

Heres my attempt at using it with way points..

```
 .test {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
    animation-name: clip-text;
    color: $grey;
    white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: default;
}

.js-dipper-animate {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: text-revealer;
  content: "";
        z-index: 999;
        background-color: $grey;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: 0 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Heres a gif of the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Rcw.jpg
As you can see, the animation plays but theres no text. It should show 'test'. After the animation plays I want to be able to see the text, like 'Skills' in the gif shown

Answer (score 0):

working now, solution posted below

```
`.test,
.test::after {
    animation-delay: 0ms;
    animation-iteration-count: var(--iterations, 1);
    animation-duration: var(--duration, 800ms);
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.test {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
    color: $grey;
    white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: default;
}

.js-dipper-animate {
  position: relative;
    animation-name: clip-text;
    color: $grey;
    white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 1;

  &::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: $grey;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: 0 50%;
        pointer-events: none;
    animation-name: text-revealer;
    opacity: 1;
    }
}`
```